# Launch terminal in su mode XFCE

Tags: terminal, xfce

I want to set up a launcher for my terminal in XFCE that automatically prompts for the su password, in gnome my shortcut was:

```
gnome-terminal --command="su -" --geometry=180x40+400+80
```

How do I configure the XFCE shortcut for that? the current properties are:

```
exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be `gksu "exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator"` use `gksu` to get root access with graphical software. try `gksu gedit` or `gksu mousepad` to see what I mean.

Comment: There would be a trivial problem if root is using a different "Preferred Terminal Emulator"

Comment: it should be `gksu "exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator"`, need to enclose the command line within quotation marks

Answer (score 0):

I'm running xfce 4.10 ,

Here , in the "Prefered Applications" in the settings dialog , or just run the command:

`exo-preferred-applications`

In `Terminal` , choose "other" , and the dialog pops up:

[image]

Not sure how programs that runs in terminal works , you might not get those functions after this

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple answer for this:

1. Create a launcher.
2. Make sure "Launch in terminal" is selected.
3. Then set the command line to `sudo su` and click save.

When run terminal opens and asks for the password. Works great.

**Edit:**

Also `sudo -i` and `xterm -bg black -fg red -e sudo -i` supposedly work.

For the `xterm` option uncheck the launch in terminal option.

Happy root terminals.

Comment: By default, `sudo` asks for the password of the user who launches `sudo`, although this can be configured. OP, however, specifically asks for the "su password", by which they probably mean root's password. `su` alone asks for it, so that there is no need for `sudo`. Similarly, `sudo -i` performs the same as `su -`, except that, again, it normally doesn't ask for the root password. Finally, you may want to elaborate what you mean by the last sentence "For the xterm option...".